# SSISDB on AlwaysOn Group running package on Secondary Replica

Tags: sql-server

I have sql server 2016 Enterprise Edition. I have created AlwaysOn Group. and added SSISDB. I do have couple SSIS packages running on primary replica with no errors. but when failing over to second replica, the jobs fails.

Asking to create master Key or certificate.

so my question is this: is there a way to automate this and whenever FaillOver happen the jobs should be running as they are on Primary replica?

Thank you all.

Rashid

Answer (score 1):

> ... but when failing over to second replica, the jobs fails.
>
> Asking to create master Key or certificate.

This is due to how security works with keys in SQL Server. There are [various](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2015/08/21/ssis-package-execution-failure-when-ssisdb-is-configured-with-alwayson/) methods [around](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/backup-restore-and-move-the-ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2014) this.

> is there a way to automate this and whenever FaillOver happen the jobs should be running as they are on Primary replica?

For the first part, yes, see the second link above. For the second part, IMHO you shouldn't be executing any SSIS jobs on a SQL Server because they don't play well together in terms of sharing resources. Period. You're asking for performance issues when doing this and I'd stay far, far away from it.